# Is there a way to trace mysql connection requests?

Tags: php, mysql

If I've got the user, host, command type, thread id and argument (data from the mysql general log), how do I determine the origin of the command, as-in what script or application did it come from? Just knowing that info doesn't tell me much. I'm trying to find out where it is coming from.

I have checked my php and apache logs but was unable to determine what might be issuing the commands. I need some sort of direct trace.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to know on the MySQL server side what application the connection came from. The only identifying information the MySQL server can log is the user and the host from which the connection originated.

Some people design their apps to add comments to the SQL queries, and the comment is added to the query log:

```
SELECT ... FROM mytable /* ShoppingCart.java, method cancelOrder() */
```

But if your apps don't do that, the information is of course not available.

Also the `mysql` client strips comments before submitting the query, so if you have SQL scripts or users making ad hoc queries, this method doesn't work.

Comment: damn. I am having this problem where I keep getting "connect" commands, about 3 per second with the user being root. root is the same user my website uses to connect to the database - but I'm unsure if it actually is a script on my website issuing the command. i guess the only way to determine if it is something on my website would be to delete the entire website, check, and reupload. i'd like to avoid doing that though.

Comment: @ChrisScott If you've got a single include for the connection, you could create a new user, grant this user the rights needed and change the credentials in this include. If it's spread then an editor with search and replace over files would be convenient.

Comment: I've actually discovered the origin. Literally anytime anything from my server connects to mysql, the user the command used will continually issue these "connect" commands while mysql is still running. It's bizzare: http://community.bitnami.com/t/help-keep-getting-connection-commands-to-mysql-slows-down-my-server/26037

Comment: You could change the password for the MySQL root user, and see what breaks. :-) You shouldn't use root as the user your applications use to connect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try php function named `debug_backtrace()` ?
It returns an array which contains the backtrace function callings with file name line and function name.

Like this:

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();
var_dump($trace);
```

I only answer this because you have PHP tag in your question,so this is the most you can do in PHP i guess.

Comment: but where would i put this? in any ol php file on my server? I can only suspect it is php issuing the commands.